# Backmatter sections in tableofcontens are wrongly pointing to mainmatter sections in scrbook

Tags: table-of-contents, scrbook

In the tableofcontents chapters and sections in the backmatter are pointing to chapters and sections in the mainmatter. Interestingly this is not the case with the book class. Do I have a misconception on backmatter and tableofcontents?

.tex

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Chapter}

\mainmatter
\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}

\backmatter
\chapter{Backmatter Chapter}
\section{Backmatter Section}
\subsection{Backmatter Subsection}

\end{document}
```

.toc

```
\contentsline {chapter}{\nonumberline Chapter}{iii}{chapter*.2}%
\contentsline {chapter}{\numberline {1}Chapter}{1}{chapter.1}%
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1.1}Section}{1}{section.1.1}%
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {1.1.1}Subsection}{1}{subsection.1.1.1}%
\contentsline {chapter}{\nonumberline Backmatter Chapter}{3}{chapter*.3}%
\contentsline {section}{\numberline {1}Backmatter Section}{3}{section.1.1}%
\contentsline {subsection}{\numberline {1.1}Backmatter Subsection}{3}{subsection.1.1.1}%
\providecommand \tocbasic@end@toc@file {}\tocbasic@end@toc@file
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get warnings about duplicated destination names in the log. You need to make them unique, e.g.

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Chapter}

\mainmatter
\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}

\backmatter\renewcommand\theHsection{backmatter.\thesection}
\chapter{Backmatter Chapter}
\section{Backmatter Section}
\subsection{Backmatter Subsection}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks @ulrike-fischer . Having to make things like `\backmatter\renewcommand\theHsection{backmatter.\thesection}` made me think, that I have a misconception about the backmatter. It seemed unlikely, that Markus Kohm implemented it in a way, that I have to add this line. And if that is the way to do it makes me wonder why he implemented it this way. Any ideas about that?

Comment: I wondered about it too, but I can't see anything adapting the hyperref numbering. On the other side: if is rather unusual to have numbered sections below an (unnumbered) chapter in the backmatter. Normally one use \appendix and for this the link works fine.